# Duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` when adding pallet_node_authorization (or any other pallet) impl section to the lib.rs

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

Adding the below section to the rs.lib file

```
impl pallet_node_authorization::Config for Runtime {
   type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
   type MaxWellKnownNodes = MaxWellKnownNodes;
   type MaxPeerIdLength = MaxPeerIdLength;
   type AddOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
   type RemoveOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
   type SwapOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
   type ResetOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
   type WeightInfo = ();
  }
```

produce this error when building the node::

```
duplicate lang item in crate sp_io (which frame_support depends on): panic_impl.

       = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/ubuntu/substrate/substrate_auth_palet/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-u
nknown/release/deps/libsp_io-05621afa7ed3c196.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/ubuntu/substrate/substrate_auth_palet/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-
unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-276985975586ba28.rmeta
```

(without this section --> no error when building the node)

The same error occurs when add the last row to the construct_runtime

```
construct_runtime!(
        pub struct Runtime
        where
                Block = Block,
                NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
                UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
        {
                System: frame_system,
                RandomnessCollectiveFlip: 
                    pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
                Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
                Aura: pallet_aura,
                Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
                Balances: pallet_balances,
                TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
                Sudo: pallet_sudo,
 
                TemplateModule: pallet_template,
                NodeAuthorization: pallet_node_authorization::{Pallet, 
                    Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>}
        }
);
```

The lib.rs file includes this section: `#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]`.

Any idea on how to prevent this error?

My Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "node-template-runtime"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "A fresh FRAME-based Substrate node, ready for hacking."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }

pallet-aura = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-randomness-collective-flip = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-sudo = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-try-runtime = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-timestamp = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-executive = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-block-builder = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-core = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-inherents = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-offchain = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-runtime = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-std = { version = "5.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-transaction-pool = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-version = { version = "5.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }    

# Used for the node template's RPCs
frame-system-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35">

# Used for runtime benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-system-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35>

# Local Dependencies
pallet-template = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/template" }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { version = "5.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
        "frame-try-runtime?/std",
        "frame-system-benchmarking?/std",
        "frame-benchmarking?/std",
        "codec/std",
       "scale-info/std",
        "frame-executive/std",
        "frame-support/std",
        "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
        "frame-system/std",
        "frame-try-runtime/std",
        "pallet-aura/std",
        "pallet-balances/std",
        "pallet-grandpa/std",
        "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/std",
        "pallet-sudo/std",
        "pallet-template/std",
        "pallet-timestamp/std",
        "pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std",
        "pallet-transaction-payment/std",
        "sp-api/std",
        "sp-block-builder/std",
        "sp-consensus-aura/std",
        "sp-core/std",
        "sp-inherents/std",
        "sp-offchain/std",
        "sp-runtime/std",
        "sp-session/std",
        "sp-std/std",
        "sp-transaction-pool/std",
        "sp-version/std",
        "pallet-node-authorization/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = [
        "frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
        "frame-support/runtime-benchmarks",
        "frame-system-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
        "frame-system/runtime-benchmarks",
        "pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks",
        "pallet-grandpa/runtime-benchmarks",
        "pallet-template/runtime-benchmarks",
        "pallet-timestamp/runtime-benchmarks",
        "sp-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
]
try-runtime = [
        "frame-try-runtime/try-runtime",
        "frame-executive/try-runtime",
        "frame-system/try-runtime",
        "frame-support/try-runtime",
        "pallet-aura/try-runtime",
        "pallet-balances/try-runtime",
        "pallet-grandpa/try-runtime",
        "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/try-runtime",
        "pallet-sudo/try-runtime",
        "pallet-template/try-runtime",
        "pallet-timestamp/try-runtime",
        "pallet-transaction-payment/try-runtime",
]
```

Comment: Can you share the full Cargo.toml? This error can be an issue with versions

Comment: Just did @AlexBean

Comment: @AlexBean - I tried to change polkadot branch from 9.35 to 34 and 33 but didn't solve it

Answer (score 1):

This error is mostly about that not having `std` feature of any dependency in `cargo.toml`.

In your case, `pallet-nicks` does not have std feature in `Cargo.toml`. Either remove `pallet-nicks`, if you are not using it or add `pallet-nicks/std` in std features list.

Comment: It is not relevant, even if it is not needed.         I just add this pallet to test it too and it creates the same problem. I also tried to build without it and the issue still exists.

Comment: BTW: I tried it on 2 separate machine and the issue returned on itself.  (Linux and mac)

Comment: @PazDiamant
As I said, in most of the cases,  not having std feature of any dependency in cargo.toml could be the reason. There might be other reasons as well. I can also see wrong versions in your `Cargo.toml`.

Can you correct versions in your `Cargo.toml`? For ex: In your `Cargo.toml`, you have used `7.0.0` for `sp-core`. Ideally it should be 6.0.0 according to this https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.33/primitives/core/Cargo.toml#L3 same for `sp-runtime`. Please check for other dependencies too

Comment: thanks @Ayush-Mishra, this is not the culprit, i just tried it with 9.33 , 9.34, 9.35 (see changes in the above code) and in 9.35 the sp-core should be v 7.0.0(if I'm not mistaken). I also do not see any missing std feature. Wil be great if you can please give me one. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version and now the problem does not exists